# Finding all pairs with difference of 's' in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array in length **n** with integers in the range **[0,n^5]**. I want to find **all** pairs in the array for which the difference between them is a given integer variable of value **s** (for example for integers a,b in the array, we will either have a-b=s or b-a=s if they meet the given requirement).

What is the best deterministic algorithm (i.e without using hashset or similiarities) to find all of the pairs? Can I do it in **O(n)** time complexity?

My idea is first sorting the array with Radix-Sort in O(n) time, and then somehow finding all the pairs using the fact that the array is sorted 
But I'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: If the array is sorted, and you are looking at index `i`, you only have to go through all the indices `j > i` until `arr[j] - arr[i] > s`. Assuming your array does not have duplicates, your lookahead will be at most `s` steps so this gives you a time complexity of O(ns) = O(n).

Comment: @CompuChip **s** is not constant, and there might be duplicates.

Comment: If there are duplicates, you want to have duplicates in the result? Like if array is [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], and `s` is 1, then what should be the output?

Comment: @trincot no need for duplicates in the output, but in order to avoid slowing the algorithm (by searching if I already inserted the given pair to the array), we can allow duplicates in the output (hence - it doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the array is sorted with radix sort (assuming inputs provide complexity O(n)) you could use a two pointer approach where p1 and p2 are both at the beginning of the array and you iterate through the array until p2 < number of elements in the array

rough pseudocode..

```
while p2 < array.length && p1 < array.length
  if array[p2] - array[p1] == k
    increment count of unique pairs
    increment p1
    increment p2
  else if array[p2] - array[p1] > k
    increment p1
  else 
    increment p2
  end
end
```

EDIT: 
`p1 < array.length` for negative s values.

Comment: will this work if there are duplicates in the array?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I think the case where they are equal and we increment both deals with the problem of duplicates (I do not care that there will be or not duplicates in the final output, i.e for s=3  4,4,7,7 is not needed).

Kris - looks really good, will it work with a possible negative s and possible negative values in the array?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz It does not account for duplicates. For array [0, 0, 100, 100, 200] the pseudocode would increment 3 times for (0, 100), (0, 100), (100, 200). We can edit the pseudocode so that if array[p2] - array[p1] == k we increment p2 until array[p2 - 1] !== array[p2]

Comment: @Mickey for negative s p1 would increment at a greater rate than p2 so I think we'd just have to check for p2 < array.length and p1 <array.length in the while condition. Going back to what I said earlier about skipping duplicates we'd also increment p1 until array[p1 - 1] !== array[p1] for negative s.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to build a hash table with the counts of the integers. Then for each key a in the hash table you can check if [s+a] exists. To me this seems a bit more efficient than sorting, but should be tested with different sizes on n.